# Qual é o correto: morrer de câncer ou morrer com câncer?

Tags: ortografia

Qual é o mais correto falar ,morrer de câncer ou morrer com câncer, estou com essa dúvida pois já ouvi pessoas falando dos dois jeitos.

Answer (score 6):

Ambas estão corretas, mas *de* é (marginalmente) mais claro, já que indica necessariamente a causa da morte, enquanto *com* pode indicar circunstâncias presentes por ocasião da morte, mas que não contribuíram para ela. Por exemplo, é pelo menos possível dizer algo do género:

> Morreu com um cancro avançado no pâncreas, mas a causa da morte foi mesmo o camião que o atropelou.

Usar aqui *de* é impossível.

Comment: então no caso do câncer seria mais correto dizer a pessoa morreu de câncer?

Answer (score 3):

Em pt-BR, fazemos a seguintes distinção:

"morrer de" refere-se à causa mortis.  Quem morre, morre de alguma coisa (causa)

> - Ele morreu de AIDS.
> - Ela morreu de tanto rir.
> - Meu avô morreu de câncer (ou "cancro" em pt-PT) na próstata.

"morrer com" também é usado, mas em contexto bem diferente.

> - Ele morreu com apenas 34 anos.
> - Ele morreu com um tiro na boca.
> - Ele morreu com a esposa (junto com) em um acidente.

Para indicar a causa mortis, "morreu de" é idiomático.

Em tempo: em pt-BR, cancro é, mais frequentemente, um termo utilizado pelo leigo para designar dois tipos de DST.

Comment: Eu vi certa vez uma paletar de uma Medica que disse que não realmente não a registros de pessoas que Morreram de AIDS pois essa doença baixa imunidade e os pacientes morem com outras doenças como gripe ou infecção por conta da baixa imunidade... por isso disse que as pessoas morem com AIDS

Answer (score 0):

Morreu com um cancro = ele tinha um cancro quando morreu.

Morreu de cancro = cancro foi a sua causa de morte.